# Getting response 404 when making requests from text files. Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to read my URL-s from a text file, but when I print the response I get Response 404. When I put that same URL directly in the requests function, I get Response 200.
Here is my code:

```
import requests

file=open("/home/ilija/Downloads/dealerinspire1.txt","r")
for i in file.readlines():
    page=requests.get(i)
    print(page)
```

Content of the text file:

```
https://www.somewebsite.com
https://www.somewebsite1.com
```

Comment: Maybe use `strip` to remove the `\n`?

Comment: It worked thanks @DeepSpace

Answer (score 0):

Just add strip(), and it works properly.

```
import requests

file=open("/home/ilija/Downloads/dealerinspire1.txt")
for i in file.readlines():
    page=requests.get(i.strip())
    print(page)
```